# How do I access a class declared inside another class?

Tags: c++, class

I have a simple class:

```
class cup{
public:
     cup();
     void drinkwater(water *t); // error occurs here
private:
     class water{
     public:
          int litres;
     };
};
```

However I get an error saying that 'water' has not been declared. Is there any way to access the class without having to put the water class outside?

Comment: Same as you do for Namespacing: `cup::water`

Comment: Declare if before you refer to it in `drinkwater`. See [this example](http://ideone.com/AXWNzB). But you should clarify how you intend to use this.

Comment: Just for reference, you *could* use it even while `private`. [(<s>I believe</s> that's legal)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94c94fea7f980dfe) (I checked, it is). But as @juanchopanza said, knowing your intend would be good.

Comment: I just wanna do some operations on it like give litres a value.

Comment: If you want to use `water` from outside `cup`, it should probably be declared `public` or not nested at all.

Comment: Move the privates above the public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward-declare `class water;` in a private section above the definition of `drinkwater`, like

```
class cup{
    class water;
public:
     cup();
     void drinkwater(water *t); // error occurs here
private:
     class water{
     public:
          int litres;
     };
};
```